# Grouping a column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by

I'm trying to group a column in my MYSQL table called "set" and I'm trying to retrieve the lowest page_id of that set.

```
SELECT * FROM pages WHERE project_id ='$project_id' GROUP BY `set` ORDER BY page_id ASC
```

How would I go about doing this properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`MIN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min) aggregate function:

```
SELECT MIN(page_id) AS lowest_page_id
FROM pages 
WHERE project_id ='$project_id' 
GROUP BY `set`
```

Comment: Prefect! Thank you very much! I have learned a new function :-)!